# Comparing two strings in R. How does this work?

Tags: r

I'm using R right now...and I'm wondering why this is true.

```
> 'dog' > 'cat'
[1] TRUE
> 'cat' > 'dog'
[1] FALSE
```

Why is dog greater than cat here?

Comment: According to `?Comparison` `Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic within the strings using the collating sequence of the locale in use: see locales. The collating sequence of locales such as en_US is normally different from C (which should use ASCII) and can be surprising. Beware of making any assumptions about the collation order: e.g. in Estonian Z comes between S and T, and collation is not necessarily character-by-character – in Danish aa sorts as a single letter, after z...`

Comment: What exactly does this mean..

Comment: Start comparing at the first letter. `d` comes later in the alphabet than `c` so `"d">"c"` so `"dog">"cat"`